# Function countDown not workin properly

Tags: javascript

I want to make the function countDown() do -0.2 every 5 minutes but when i run it does -0.2 the first time and the second time it does -1.2
how can i fix this?

```
var temperatuur = 7.2;

        function openDedeur() {
            temperatuur = temperatuur + Math.ceil(0.9);
            document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur;
            console.log("U hebt de wijnkoeler geopend, de temperatuur stijgt nu met ca. 0.9º.");
        }

        function countDown() {
            setInterval(function() {
                temperatuur = temperatuur - 0.2;
                document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur;
            }, 3000);
        }
```

Comment: 3000 milliseconds will have the function run every 3 seconds. Nevertheless you mentioned 5 minutes, is that expected?

Comment: @BelgianMyWaffle: The 3 second is probably for testing purposes.

Comment: @user: Aside from floating point math issues, your code works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/8SCmB/ If you have an issue, it isn't demonstrated in the code you gave.

Comment: Exactly.The 3 seconds Its for testing

Comment: can you please put your html as well?

Comment: Can i fix those math issues?

Comment: `.value = temperatuur.toFixed(1)` if you know the number of decimal places. If you need more info, there are lots of questions on SO that deal with this.

Comment: Thanks dude! THe Countdown also works now! (y)